# Why Jupyter lab is very slow for searching text?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I have a big notebook and using Jupyter lab the running is actually very fast which I like . However searching for a text is very slow.  This situation is opposite to using Jupyter notebook. Using Jupyter notebook only, searching is fast but running code is slow, sometimes it does not have table of contents.

Is there a way to make Jupyter lab faster in searching for a text?

Thanks

Comment: you mean executing python code that searches for text in a string or a file?

Comment: no, I just tried to search any text inside the code

Comment: What version of JupyterLab?

Comment: Hi Krassowski,   jupyterlab       : 3.3.2

Comment: 1) there is a PR which will improve performance: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/11689 you are very welcome to benchmark it with your large notebook (just click on the [Binder badge](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fcollonval/jupyterlab/ft%2Fsearch-based-model?urlpath=lab-dev) it should open the version with the patch applied). 2) pressing ctrl + f twice will bring the browser search bar; this one might be faster (but no replace function in it)

Comment: Thanks glad to hear that I am very excited. I will try later today

Comment: Thanks Krassowski, how to use it? I open binder badge which is a jupyter lab. where I can download it? also I cannot open this binder badge inside my company it is blocked. I can only open it at home, is there anything like command like pip install something?